# Problema com um modal button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bom estou com um problema eu fiz um modal button, mas só está abrindo a primeira foto, a do cliente 1, as outras 3 ( cliente 2 3 4) não acontece nada qnd clica ..

```css
.nav.nav-justified > li > a { position: relative; }
.nav.nav-justified > li > a:hover,
.nav.nav-justified > li > a:focus { background-color: transparent; }
.nav.nav-justified > li > a > .quote {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #13c0ba;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #fff;  
}
.nav.nav-justified > li.active > a > .quote { opacity: 1; }
.nav.nav-justified > li > a > img { box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #13c0ba; }
.nav.nav-justified > li > a > img { 
    max-width: 100%; 
    opacity: .3; 
    -webkit-transform: scale(.8,.8);
            transform: scale(.8,.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
            transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
.nav.nav-justified > li.active > a > img,
.nav.nav-justified > li:hover > a > img,
.nav.nav-justified > li:focus > a > img { 
    opacity: 1; 
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
            transition: all 0.3s 0s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
.tab-pane .tab-inner { padding: 30px 0 20px; }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .nav.nav-justified > li > a > .quote {
        left: auto;
        top: auto;
        right: 20px;
        bottom: 0px;
    }  
}

#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #FFAE00;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #FF0004;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.fotdepoi{
 background-color: #DCDADA;
}
.fotdepoi h2{
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
 text-shadow: 1px 2px 1px #000;
 font-size: 60px;
 font-weight: 700;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
 color:#0D9ECB;
}
.fotdepoi p{
 color:#000;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
     <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<section class="fotdepoi">
<div class="[ container text-center ]">
    <div class="[ row ]">
  <div class="textdep">
  <h2>Depoimento  de Clientes </h2>
  </div>
        <div class="[ col-xs-12 ]" style="padding-bottom: 5px; text-align: center;">
            <p>Depoimentos de clientes <br>Navegue clicando nos icones.</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="[ container text-center ]">
 <div class="[ row ]">
  <div class="[ col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 ]" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="[ col-xs-4 col-sm-12 ]">
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="[ nav nav-justified ]" id="nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active">
                        <a href="#dustin" aria-controls="dustin" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            <img class="img-circle" src="https://www.renderosity.com/templates/renderositybootstrap/image/default_avatar.png" />
                            <span class="quote"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="">
                        <a href="#daksh" aria-controls="daksh" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            <img class="img-circle" src="https://www.renderosity.com/templates/renderositybootstrap/image/default_avatar.png" />
                            <span class="quote"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="">
                        <a href="#anna" aria-controls="anna" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            <img class="img-circle" src="https://www.renderosity.com/templates/renderositybootstrap/image/default_avatar.png" />
                            <span class="quote"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="">
                        <a href="#wafer" aria-controls="wafer" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            <img class="img-circle" src="https://www.renderosity.com/templates/renderositybootstrap/image/default_avatar.png" />
                            <span class="quote"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="[ col-xs-8 col-sm-12 ]">
                <!-- Tab panes -->
                <div class="tab-content" id="tabs-collapse">            
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="dustin">
                        <div class="tab-inner">                    
                            <p class="lead">Cliente 1 : - Cara empresa de responsa msm.
Garantiu o 10/0 da minha md10 rápido, e olha que duvidei...
Sem dúvidas foi um dinheiro bem aplicado!
Agora aproveitar a season livre dos trolls kkk.. 
Obrigado mesmo pessoal, ja tem um cliente e pode crer que vai ter bem mais, pq eu vou indicar pra vários brothers meus desde ja.
Obrigado mesmo... sucesso ai!</p>
                            <hr>
                            <p><strong class="text-uppercase">O Cliente comprou MD10 elo: Prata .</strong></p>
                      <img id="myImg" src="http://hdwarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Beautiful-Wallpaper.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="100">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

                            <p>Clique na imagem acima para ver as FOTOS do serviço.</p>               
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="daksh">
                        <div class="tab-inner">
                            <p class="lead">Cliente 2: - Maravilhosos! equipe de profissionais, super seguro e confiáveis, trabalho rápido e profissional...super recomendado.</p>
                            <hr>
 <p><strong class="text-uppercase">O Cliente comprou MD10 ELO : GOLD 5.</strong></p>
 <img id="myImga" src="http://hdwarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Beautiful-Wallpaper.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="200" height="100">
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="imga">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
<p>Clique na imagem acima para ver as FOTOS do serviço.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="anna">
                        <div class="tab-inner">
                            <p class="lead">Cliente 3: - Serviço muito bom, em menos de um dia já tive minha MD10 completa com 10 vitórias, recomendo está empresa 100%..</p>
                            <hr>
                            <p><strong class="text-uppercase">O cliente comprou MD10 Elo: Bronze 3</strong></p>
 <img id="myImgb" src="http://hdwarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Beautiful-Wallpaper.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="200" height="100">
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="imgb">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
 <p>Clique na imagem acima para ver as FOTOS do serviço.</p>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="wafer">
                        <div class="tab-inner">
                            <p class="lead">Cliente 4: - Serviço bom e rápido com preço justo, recomendo a todos que quiserem sair do hell elo o trabalho dessa empresa, 100% confiavel.</p>
                            <hr>
                            <p><strong class="text-uppercase">O cliente comprou MD10 Elo: Platina 4</strong></p>
<img id="myImgc" src="http://hdwarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Beautiful-Wallpaper.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="200" height="100">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="imgc">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<p>Clique na imagem acima para ver as FOTOS do serviço.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
  
  </section>
```